# Playing vimeo videos in videojs

Tags: video.js, vimeo

I am using videojs-vimeo plugin in my web application to reproduce the live streaming.
It works very well but I am not able to customize the control bar.I would like to hide with css the vimeo control bar and to use my custom videojs control bar.

Is it possible?
Thanks a lot.